# Isomorphism of the quotient group involving isometry

Tags: abstract-algebra

I came across the following problem: 
What is the quotient group $Iso(\mathbb{R^2})/T$ isomorphic to? Here $T$ is the group of all translations in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

My attempt: I proved that $T$ is a normal subgroup and then I would guess that the quotient group is isomorphic to $O(2)$ where $O(2)=\{A\in Gl(n,\mathbb{R})|A^T=A^{-1}\}$ (Orthogonal group)? Am I correct? I do not know what map would satisfy this though?

Comment: When you say "*I do not know what map would satisfy this though?*", what sort of map are you asking for? The isomorphism from $\operatorname{Iso}(\mathbb{R})/T$ to $\text{O}(2)$, or which?

Comment: @FlybyNight: Yes, I am trying to use the First isomorphism theorem and so I would need a map from $Iso(\mathbb{R^2})$ to $O(2)$

Answer (score 1):

An isometry of the plane consists of a translation and an orthogonal transformation, i.e.
$$\text{Iso}(\mathbb{R}^2) \cong \text{O}(2)\ltimes T$$

We can think of this as a subgroup of $\text{GL}(3,\mathbb{R})$ as follows.  Given an orthogonal transformation $X \in \text{O}(2)$ and a translation $t \in T$, we have $(X,t) \in \text{Iso}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

To the pair $(X,t)\in \text{Iso}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ we associate the block matrix

$$\left(\begin{array}{c|c} X & t \\ \hline 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)$$
Given $(X,t)$ and $(Y,\tau)$ we have
$$ (X,t) \circ (Y,\tau) \sim \left(\begin{array}{c|c} X & \ t \\ \hline 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c|c} Y & \tau \\ \hline 0 & 1 \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c|c} XY & X\tau +t\\ \hline 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)
\sim (XY,X\tau+t)$$

For the map $\text{Iso}(\mathbb{R}^2) \to \text{O}(2)$, consider
$$\text{Iso}(\mathbb{R}^2) \hookrightarrow \text{GL}(3,\mathbb{R}) \twoheadrightarrow \text{O}(2)$$
$$(X,t) \longmapsto \left(\begin{array}{c|c} X & t \\ \hline 0 & 1 \end{array}\right) \longmapsto X$$
The kernel of $\text{GL}(3,\mathbb{R}) \twoheadrightarrow \text{O}(2)$ is the set of matrices
$$\left(\begin{array}{c|c} I_2 & t \\ \hline 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)$$
The map $\text{Iso}(\mathbb{R}^2) \hookrightarrow \text{GL}(3,\mathbb{R})$ is injective and the pre-image of the above kernel is exactly $(0,t) \in \text{Iso}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, i.e. the set of translations. Hence, the kernel of the map $\text{Iso}(\mathbb{R}^2) \to \text{O}(2)$ is the set of translations. As you say, the first isomorphism theorem allows you to conclude your result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a map $Q$ from $Iso(R^2)$ to the quotient group:

$f \mapsto  [(x, y) \mapsto  f(x, y) - f(0, 0)]$.

In words: associate to each isomorphism $f$ the isomorphism $g$ defined by

$g(x, y) = f(x, y) - f(0, 0)$.

Then $Q$ takes $f$ to the coset $gT$.

The function $g$ always has $(0,0)$ as a fixed point, and in fact, it's the only element of $gT$ that does so. So you can build the isomorphism $f \mapsto g$ that sends $Iso(R^2)/T$ onto (OK, you have to prove surjectivity!) the set of isomorphisms fixing the origin. Those are precisely the nonsingular linear maps of the plane to itself, i.e., $GL(2, R)$.

Comment: But in order to use the First isomorphism theorem I would need a map from $Iso(\mathbb{R^2})$ to $O(2)$?